# Power BI, IF statement with multiple OR and AND statements

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, dax

I have a table and want to create a new column based on some columns in the table using multiple statements.

I want to do something like this:

```
NewColumn  = if( (colA>colB and colC=0)
             or (colD >colE and colF = 20)
             or colG = "blue",
             "True", "False")
```

How would I code this in DAX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In DAX you should write something like this:

```
test = 
IF(
    OR(
        OR(
            AND(
                [A]>[B]; 
                [C] = 0
            ); 
            AND(
                [D]>[E]; 
                [F] = 20
            )
        ); 
        [G] = "Blue"
    ); 
    "True"; 
    "False"
)
```

However, I do believe you'll get the same result by using something like this, though you should double check this code since I don't have your data.

```
New = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE();
    [A] > [B] && [C] = 0; "True";
    [D] > [E] && [F] = 20; "True";
    [G] = "Blue"; "True";
    "False"
)
```

Comment: I'm happy it worked for you. You can check this page for more info: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/switch-function-dax)

Comment: I had to change the ; to , in the code but otherwise its all good :)

Answer (score 2):

This would be the correct syntax. Take care and dont write in upper case.

```
= if ([ColumnA] > [ColumnB] and [ColumnC] = 0) or 
     ([ColumnD] > [ColumnE] and [ColumnF] = 20) or 
     [ColumnG] = "blue" 
  then true 
  else false
```

[image]

Comment: this is not valid DAX

Comment: Sure it works for me in the query editor under Add Column > Custom Column. And if you look on his question he wants to create a new column at his table.

Comment: @mxix In this case, the M (Power Query) language is used to create (as an extra step in the data loading process) a new column, not DAX (calculated column), thus the `IF` statement is perfectly valid.

Comment: @NickKrasnov then I think it should be explicitly stated that it is powerquery and not DAX, since the question is for DAX, but this is a valid alternative in powerquery

Comment: This is often a problem, that the person asking the question doesnt know the difference between DAX and M. Most ppl think Power BI is all about DAX, thus I provided an answer which will serve his purpose independent from the language.